# iOS Corebluetooth scan rate

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a iOS app implementing a BLE central using the corebluetooth framework
The App does a ScanForPeripheralWithServices to scan for BLE peripherals that are advertising
**Question** - How often does the iOS device scan - Is this programmable?

Answer (score 2):

Simply said: its not programmable,

I read somewhere that iPhone(assumption) a 1.28 sec scan can find up to five device but only ios takes care of scanning times (if you do not provide specific device as parameter or limit)

Scans for peripherals that are advertising services.

```
- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs 
                               options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

Parameters

serviceUUIDs

> An array of CBUUID objects that the app is interested in. In this
>   case, each CBUUID object represents the UUID of a service that a
>   peripheral is advertising.

options

> An optional dictionary specifying options to customize the scan. For
>   available options, see “Peripheral Scanning Options.”

Comment: what do you mean with "if you do not provide specific device as parameter or limit"?

Comment: Ok - Understand that it is not programmable - does Apple specify what it is.

Comment: I have been through Apple docs but i dont know how does it work actually, i guess only core Bluetooth team knows how does it work :(

Comment: What is the scan timeout? I have been working with CB for years but have never seen this term. Scanning does not time out, you start it, it runs. Also, for scan interval 1.28 seems to be quite wrong as generally it works an order of magnitude faster. Can you add the reference to this piece of info? Additionally, scanning is different in background and foreground so it is not that easy to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

What all you can do is use a Timer and call scanForPeripheralsWithServices from it and when you find correct device invalidate the timer :)